# How do I call my funtion factory with a filter?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I made a function factory in Scheme which receives a binary function f, and call it to a list of 1 or more variables.

```
(define makeDoForAll
  (lambda (f)
    (define (helper a lst)
      (if (null? lst)
       a
       (if (null? (cdr lst))
           (f a (car lst))
           (helper (f a (car lst))
                   (cdr lst)))))

    (lambda (x . others)
      (helper x others))))
```

I want to make a new function that uses this function factory to sum up all even numbers in a given list, so that `(sumEvens 1 2 3 4 5)` will output 6 for example.

How do I call the function factory while implementing the filter `(even? x)`?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: "f" should do the filtering. I the second argument is even, added it to a. If not, return a unchanged.

Comment: I doubt that it will work, as you're using a list element as the base case without passing it through `f`. In other words, your "factoried" function doesn't do anything with one-element lists.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- Nested `if` are best written as `cond` expressions.
- It looks like you are implementing a [fold](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) function.

You could generate a closure that accepts a list and performs both filtering and addition, but the simplest way to do what you want is to filter the list first, and then sum the resulting elements:

```
    (foldl + 0 (filter even? '(1 2 3 4 5)))
    => 6
```